# Error handling in C: unable to malloc in nested function

Tags: c, error-handling

In `C`, I know it is good practice to always check if a newly malloced variable is `null` right after allocating. If so, I can output an error e.g. `perror` and exit the program.

But what about in more complicated programs? E.g. I have `main` call a function `f1`(returns an `int`), which calls a function `f2`(returns a `char*`), which calls a function `f3`(returns a `double`), and I fail to malloc inside `f3`.

In this case, I can't seem to just output an error and exit(and may even have memory leaks if possible) since `f3` will still force me to first return a `double`. Then `f2` will force me to return a `char*`, etc. In this case, it seems very painful to keep track of the errors and exit appropriately. What is the proper way to efficiently cover these sort of errors accross functions?

Comment: Share your code with us ?

Comment: Better to show some example code IMO

Comment: Arguably, this question might be more appropriate over at [softwareengineering.se].

Comment: @TobySpeight when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @TonyTannous It's a general question based on something I've noticed.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to design your program with care, so that every function that does dynamic allocation has some means to report errors. Most often the return value of the function is used for this purpose.

In well-designed programs, errors bounce back all the way up the call stack, so that they are dealt with at the application level.

In the specific case of dynamic memory allocation, it is always best to leave the allocation to the caller whenever possible.

Comment: Yes but if you want to divide you program into components where one function allocates memory for an int array which calls some other function which then divides by 0 causing the whole process to terminate you will end up with a memory leak. Correct me if I am wrong please ?

Comment: @TonyTannous Yes you would end up with a memory leak, but most OS will free all dynamic memory allocated by your process at the point of termination. That is not a severe error (what's your program supposed to meaningfully continue doing after a divide by zero?) compared to for example a memory leak caused by a function repeatedly allocating memory that is not freed.

Comment: My program does nothing.. I am not OP. I just asked to be sure. Thanks for answer. But there's one thing that caught me eye, if OS frees memory at process termination, why bother and free in firstplace ?

Comment: @TonyTannous Because memory leaks chew up the memory available to your process, alternatively they make your program consume excessive amounts of RAM during execution.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a problem. You need a disiplined approach.

Firstly, every dynamic pointer must be "owned" by someone. C won't help you here, you just have to specify. Generally the three patterns are

a) Function calls malloc(), then calls free():

b) We have two matching functions, one which returns a buffer or dynamic
structure, one which destroys it. The function that calls create also calls the destroy.

c) We have a set of nodes we are inserting into a graph, at random throughout the program. It needs to be managed like b, one function creates the root, then calls the delete which destroys the entire graph.

The rule is owner holds and frees.

If you return a pointer, return 0 on out of memory. If you return an integer, return -1. Errors get propagated up until some high level code knows what user-level operation has failed and aborts it.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct that the *correct* way to handle this is to make sure that every function that can allocate memory can report failure to its caller, and every caller handles the possibility.  And, of course, you have a test `malloc` shim that arranges to test every possible allocation failure.

But in large C programs, this becomes intractable — the number of cases that need testing increases *exponentially* with the number of `malloc` callsites, for starters — so it is very common to see a function like this in a `utils.c` file:

```
void *
xmalloc(size_t n)
{
    void *rv = malloc(n);
    if (!rv) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: memory exhausted\n", program_name);
        exit(1);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

All other code in the program always calls `xmalloc`, never `malloc`, and can assume it always succeeds.  (And you also have `xcalloc`, `xrealloc`, `xstrdup`, etc.)

Libraries cannot get away with this, but applications can.

Answer (score -1):

The one way to switch across the functions is **exception handling.**

When an exception is thrown, it return the scope the catch part.

But make sure of the memory allocation across the functions, Since it directly moves to the catch blok.

The sample code for reference,

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std ;

int f1()
{
    int  *p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)) ;

    if(p == NULL)
    {
        throw(1) ;
    }
    //Code flow continues.
    return 0 ; 
}

char *g()
{
    char *p ;
    f1() ;
    cout << "Inside fun g*" << endl ; 

    return p;
}

int f2()
{
    g() ;
    cout << "Inside fun f2" << endl ; 
    return 0 ; 
}
int main()
{
    try
    {
        f2() ;
    }
    catch(int a)
    {
        cout << "Caught memory exception" << endl ; 
    }
  return  0 ;
}
```

Comment: This is a flawed design though. How is the caller supposed to know that some function called by f2, calls another function which throws a certain kind of exception? Designs like this end up with "Sudden unexplained crash. Reason: unhandled exception." Debugging crap like that is very painful.

Comment: In addition, this is tagged C, so why do you give an answer for another programming language?